# Grav - Retrieving specific items from page in template

Tags: twig, grav

I have the following page structure in Grav:

```
# Title
## Subtitle
### Subsubtitle
```

The page structure is always the same and it has just those three items.

How can I retrieve each item (Title/Subtitle/Subsubtitle) separately in Twig template?

The twig template will then do things like:

```
<p> You typed {{ page.whatever_retrieves_the_title_# }} as title, then {{ page.whatever_retrieves_the_subtitle_## }} as subtitle and finally {{ page.whatever_retrieves_the_subsubtitle_### }} as subsubtitle</p>
```

What if instead of the above structure I have:

```
- Title
- Subtitle
- Subsubtitle
```

The objective is that the user adds just that structure of three items and the twig template use each item to display a more complex layout.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to define these as vars in your header?

Comment: @PaulMassendari if I properly understood how grav admin user interface works, a user would need to select expert mode to edit those as vars in header. I would like a non-technical user being able to change that text.

Comment: not exactly, you can provide your own blueprint. I will provide an answer as an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is Markdown, right?

```
# Title
## Subtitle
### Subsubtitle
```

You can get the HTML version of the page's Markdown in Twig with `{{ page.content }}`, as described in [Grav's documentation](https://learn.getgrav.org/themes/theme-vars#content). So you should get something like this:

```
<h1>Title</h1>
<h2>Subtitle</h2>
<h3>Subsubtitle</h3>
```

You can use the `split` and `raw` filters to extract the contents of those tags. I'm also using the `default` filter so that there won't be an error if the extraction of the tag contents fails:

```
Title is:
{{ page.content|split('<h1>')[1]|default|raw|split('</h1>')[0] }}

Subtitle is:
{{ page.content|split('<h2>')[1]|default|raw|split('</h2>')[0] }}

Subsubtitle is:
{{ page.content|split('<h3>')[1]|default|raw|split('</h3>')[0] }}
```

Or because Grav seems to provide a [`regex_replace` filter](https://learn.getgrav.org/themes/twig-filters-functions#regex-replace), you could also use it:

```
Title is:
{{ page.content|regex_replace('~.*<h1>(.*)</h1>.*~s', '$1') }}

Subtitle is:
{{ page.content|regex_replace('~.*<h2>(.*)</h2>.*~s', '$1') }}

Subsubtitle is:
{{ page.content|regex_replace('~.*<h3>(.*)</h3>.*~s', '$1') }}
```

---

If instead you have this:

```
- Title
- Subtitle
- Subsubtitle
```

You can again use the `split`, `default` and `raw` filters:

```
Title is:
{{ page.content|split('<li>')[1]|default|raw|split('</li>')[0] }}

Subtitle is:
{{ page.content|split('<li>')[2]|default|raw|split('</li>')[0] }}

Subsubtitle is:
{{ page.content|split('<li>')[3]|default|raw|split('</li>')[0] }}
```

---

Not very beautiful. :-) If the titles can contain HTML (e.g. `## Hello **world**!` → `<h2>Hello <strong>world</strong>!</h2>`) or special characters, you probably need to append `|raw` to the already long magic spells.

Comment: Thanks this answers the question, however I finally found that a much better approach in Grav is to use a plugin which allows to define sections and then retrieve such sections in Twig.

Comment: @M.E. This solution here is very ugly and hacky so great if you found a better approach!

Comment: As reference I include this question which is related and have a better approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48912840/grav-using-shortcodes-in-twig/48913273#48913273

Answer (score 1):

Others provided good solution with markdown manipulation. However, you could use grav features and provide your own blueprints, and have your user fills some fields.

Let's say this is for a page that uses the template `blog_article.html.twig`, you can therefore create a file named `blog_article.yaml` inside `user/themes/yourtheme/blueprints` and fill it with the following blueprint:

```
title: Blog_Article
'@extends':
    type: default
    context: blueprints://pages

form:
  fields:
    tabs:
      fields:
        content:
          fields:
            header.mytitle:
              type: text
              label: My Label
            header.mysubtitle:
              type: text
              label: Type Subtitle
            header.mysubsubtitle
              type: text
              label: Type subsubtitle
```

Now, if you try to edit your page from admin, you will see three new fields added to the page, under the page medias.

You can then display these fields in your template with the following twig:

```
{{ page.header.mytitle }} 
{{ page.header.mysubtitle }}
{{ page.header.mysubsubtitle }}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: This is extremely interesting and I will give it a try. I have never used blueprints so far