# Grav - Using shortcodes in twig

Tags: twig, grav

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48911978/grav-retrieving-specific-items-from-page-in-template), I have found that there is a plugin named [shortcodes](https://github.com/getgrav/grav-plugin-shortcode-core/blob/master/README.md) which might be helpful here.

I have installed the plugin and created a new page:

```
---
title: slide1
media_order: slider1.jpeg
taxonomy:
    category:
        - 'Home Slider'
process:
    markdown: true
    twig: true
routable: false
cache_enable: false
visible: false
---

[section name="slide_title"]
Precisión y Calidad
[/section]

[section name="slide_subtitle"]
La máxima calidad y seguridad para nuestros clientes
[/section]

[section name="slide_link"]
www.google.es
[/section]
```

Then I have an invoked partial which makes:

```
{% for slide in taxonomy.findTaxonomy({'category': 'Home Slider'}) %}
    <span>TEST</span>
    <span>{{ slide.title }}</span>
    <span>{{ slide.shortcode.section.slide_title }}</span>
    <span>{{ slide.shortcode.section.slide_subtitle }}</span>
    <span>{{ slide.shortcode.section.slide_link }}</span>
{% endfor %}
```

But this generates just:

```
TEST
slide1
```

And it does not output the shortcode section contents.

Comment: Try `{{ slide.contentMeta.shortcodeMeta.shortcode.section.slide_title }}` etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation you linked to shows the correct syntax when you are not dealing directly with the `page` variable:

```
{{ slide.contentMeta.shortcodeMeta.shortcode.section.slide_title }}
{{ slide.contentMeta.shortcodeMeta.shortcode.section.slide_subtitle }}
{{ slide.contentMeta.shortcodeMeta.shortcode.section.slide_link }}
```